# How to apply "id" in the following Code of Jquery

Tags: jquery

Dynamically created an element  under the element having class "parent"
and applied some css class to it i.e "child"
now i want to apply some "id" to it so i want to know how to do it

```
$(".parent").append("<a class='child' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");
```

and how to bind some event to it like mouse over event to it

i tried this but didn't worked

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a id='$(this).text()' class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'>".bind("mouseover", function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }) + "</a>");
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: why do you want an id? are you trying to add an id to the anchor element

Comment: okay let me Edit my Question

Comment: and how can i apply some event to it, like mouse over event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple id:

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a id='someid' class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");
```

Dynamic id:

1)

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a id='someid"+variable_name+"' class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");
```

2)

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a id='"+variable_name+"' class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");
```

Binding event:

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").on("mouseover","#someid",function(){
    //execute statements
});
```

Comment: Crystal Clear answer ! :)

Comment: and how can i apply some event to it, like mouse over event?

Comment: @Faizan like this: `$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").on("mouseover","#someid",function(){//execute statements});`

Comment: cant i add the event in the same line i meant in the same function?

Comment: @Faizan like this?? `$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a onmouseover='somefunction()' id='someid' class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");`

Comment: yah like this only, but the function not working, i meant its not calling the function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a id="'pushLinkBtn_' + cAnchorCount + '" class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".pushLinkBtnContainer").append("<a id='" + cAnchorCount + '" class='pushLinkBtn' href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "+ $(this).text()  +"</a>");
```